# My DoubleBinding throws a StackOverflowError inside a JavaFX controller class' initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Title says it all, mostly. I took the code from another StackOverflow answer, and I tried another variation that subclasses the DoubleBinding class, but the error is still there. This is for a game, and I'm trying to make a health bar of sorts. I'm thinking that it has to do with how the FXMLLoader calls the initialize method but so far I haven't found anything.

```
public void initialize() {
    // ... some code
    Rectangle hpBarInside = new Rectangle(100.0, 10.0);

    DoubleProperty healthPercent = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
    DoubleBinding b1 = healthPercent.multiply(hpBarInside.widthProperty());

    hpBarInside.widthProperty().bind(b1);
    // ... some more code
}
```

Comment: If either `healthPercent` or the width of `hpBarInside` change, then `b1` changes (because of how you define `b1`), which causes the width of `hpBarInside` to change (because of the second binding), which then causes `b1` to change, which... etc. etc. What are you trying to express here? At the moment you are making `hpBarInside.width` try to set itself to `healthPercent` multiplied by itself, which simply can't work (unless `healthPercent` is either zero or one).

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra i edited the question to be hopefully reproducible

Comment: @James_D i tried to use the code from this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/javafx-how-do-i-create-a-health-bar but i have an admittedly limited knowledge of bindings, so i do not fully understand how this works. i basically want to change `hpBarInside`'s width every time `healthPercent` changes, just like how an HP bar would work. `hpBarInside`'s width should be dependent on `healthPercent`

Comment: so after trying to understand @James_D's comment, i seem to have fixed the problem. i made it so my `DoubleBinding b1 = healthPercent.multiply(hpBarInside.widthProperty().get());` and the error goes away. hopefully, i understand bindings well.

Comment: do you have a magic api, that runs that snippet without change/addions? Want it too :) Please read the referenced help page and act accordingly.